# Мгновенные сообщения: прочтение сообщений

Tags: javascript

Как правильно реализовать прочтение новых сообщений?

Речь идет о **беседах** аля ***Диалоги во ВКонтакте***.

- Когда человек находится на странице и
     фокус установлен в поле написания
     сообщения - новые сообщения
     автоматически считать прочитанными.
- Когда человек провел мышкой по
     сообщению - тоже.
- Когда человек
     вернулся во вкладку\таб. НО. Как быть
     с сообщениями которые не видны,
     допустим новые сообщения не видны
     из-за скролла?

Еще какие варианты?

Comment: Я б за такие сценарии поведения бил бы морду. Ненавязчивое уведомление и явный клик по нему, только так.

Comment: @klopp, я думаю Вы не правы, возможно потому, что не поняли что я реализовываю.

Comment: Возможно. Ну так и задачи нужно формулировать правильно :)

Comment: @klopp прав, т.к. то, что я сообщение увидел, не доказывает, что я его прочитал

Comment: @Spectre, что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контакте, кстати, не всегда сообщения считаются прочитанными, когда фокус в поле написания находится. Там, по-моему, только при **установки** фокуса в поле сообщения считаются прочитанными. Это с одной стороны правильно. Например, я начал набирать сообщение, но тут мне по телефону звонят, или меня приспичило в туалет сходить (уж извините). Соответственно, в это время я не имею возможности прочитать новые сообщения, хотя все предыдущие я прочитал, и даже начал отвечать.

В ваши условия я бы добавил еще и следующие:

- onkeydown
- при скроллинге блока с сообщениями проверяем, находится ли сообщение в зоне видимости определенное время (чтобы исключить случай, быстрого скроллинга). Например, мы обнаружили, что новое сообщение попадает в зону видимости, делаем setTimeout на секунду, и проверяем через секунду то же самое сообщение.

А так, имхо, вы правильно рассуждаете.

> Когда человек вернулся во вкладку\таб. НО. Как быть с сообщениями которые не видны, допустим новые сообщения не видны из-за скролла?

Я бы сделал так. Когда человек возвращается во вкладку, проходимся с jquery по всем новым сообщениям и смотрим их position(). Если позиция не находится в интервале scrollTop() + height(), то пропускаем данное сообщение.

P.S. Еще... Может я и капитаном очевидностью буду, но чтобы не отправлять ajax-запросы на каждое непрочитанное сообщение (имею в виду: `update messages set read = 1 where mes_id =...`), можно, например, отправлять массив таких сообщений каждые 5-10 секунд. Т.е. накапливать сообщения и бросать их кучкой серверу на обработку.

Comment: Про пакетную отправку отлично. Только как узнать что сообщение не видно из-за скролла?

Comment: @exec, я же написал Вам... Cмотрим позицию сообщения и проверяем находится ли она в интервале [scrollTop(), scrollTop() + height()]

Ну вот так например... http://jsfiddle.net/dobby007/EFpLv/18/

Comment: @Dobby007, большое спасибо.