# Количество непрочитанных сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с сообщениями.

Как составить запрос так, чтобы он возвращал только те сообщения которые не получили ответа.

То есть, есть таблица

```
id|dialog|is_read|mess - это примерная таблица для наглядности
1 |1     |0      |265
2 |1     |1      |ыва
3 |1     |0      |ваи
4 |1     |0      |123
```

В таблице есть поле ts (unix timestamp);

Необходимо возвратить две последних строки, потому как строка с id = 1 уже получила ответ (id = 2), просто скорее всего метка о прочтении не успела отправиться на сервер и измениться.

Поле dialog не константа, это id диалога.

Этот вопрос связан с этим [**Мгновенные сообщения: прочтение сообщений**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/183035/javascript-%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) - чтоб понятно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from `your_table` where `dialog`=$dialog and (`id`>(select max(`id`) from `your_table` where `is_read`=1 and `dialog`=$dialog) or (select count(*) from `your_table` where `is_read`=1 and `dialog`=$dialog)=0)
```

Советую еще раз продумать структуру БД.

Comment: Найдена проблема: если отправлено одно сообщение, то запрос возвращает 0.

Comment: Проблема актуальна!

Comment: Обновил ответ.